# What is the default http protocol version for WebClientProtocol for .Net 4.5.1

Tags: .net, http

Right now, my program is trying to invoke a remote SOAP web service call. The way we did the invoking is:

```
WebClientProtocol clientProtocol = new WebClientProtocol ;
...........
...........Specify attributes of clientProtocol............;
...........
method.Invoke(clientProtocol , parameters);
```

However, I cannot specify the http protocol version of the WebClientProtocol. I wonder if there is a way to specify?

and I also wonder how the .Net framework decides what version of HTTP to use? Does it default to HTTP 1.1? or does it do automatic detecting of what version of HTTP the remote server is using and set to that version of HTTP?